# Windows 7 Pagefile on Mounted Partition, on 1 HDD System: Folder Attributes/Permissions?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, pagefile, junction, attributes

I wish to put my pagefile.sys in a separate partition on the same HDD as my boot partition, mounted on a folder in the tree of my boot partition — say "$PagePart".

My question: should $PagePart folder be created with special attributes/permissions and if yes, what should these special attributes/permissions be? Are there any specific guidelines?

Comment: In general this is a bad idea. Seeing that it's just one drive, and it's a hard drive, this will increase seek times to the pagefile. What is your purpose in doing this?

Comment: Regarding permissions, etc. When you create a pagefile with the Control Panel applet you are using a utility that runs with admin privileges. And pagefile access under the OS is also done with, essentially, admin privileges. As far as I know, if you can create the pagefile, it'll work and it won't care what the permissions on the partition or the directory are. Have you tried it?

Comment: @JamieHanrahan
Comments appreciated, however do not answer my question — I wish to know whether there are any specific guidelines on this [or whether there is “prior art” in the field].

My purpose is simply to keep things tidy: get out of the way objects [the pagefile.sys, in this case] I can do nothing about — not even take a look at their properties!

As for increased seek times, no, practically they won’t increase, as the pagefile.sys will still be on the same drive.

Comment: Yes, they will increase. Arm-movement time increases roughly linearly as the number of cylinders the heads have to cross increases. Your OS partition occupies one span of cylinders. If you leave the pagefile in its typical location within that partition it will be within that same span of cylinders. Putting the pagefile in a different partition puts it in a different range of cylinders. The heads will therefore take longer to move between the pagefile and the files in the OS partition.

Comment: I've created a lot of pagefiles in other than the OS partitions (on other drives). This can improve performance by moving part of the IO load to another drive, and allowing that drive to leave the heads over the pagefile. (This of course only matters if you're accessing the pagefile a lot.)  I've never seen any special requirements or reccommendations for creating partitions with pagefiles. Just create the partition and leave the permissions, etc., at the defaults.